# NSMutableArray count not updating with array

Tags: objective-c, binding, xcode4

I have an NSMutableArray which I initialized like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and am populating a table with it.  I have a method to count the number of items in the array:

```
- (NSUInteger)trackCount
{
    tracks = [playlist count];
    NSLog(@"Number of tracks = %lx", tracks);
    return tracks;
}
```

and I have a label bound to my appDelegate with the model key path `trackCount`, but the label doesn't update when tracks are added(nor does the log).  What am I doing wrong??

Would it make more sense and/or be easier to get a count of the rows in the table since they should always be the same number?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done `playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` somewhere before this method is called?

Comment: `-count` works, something else doesn't!

Comment: Could you perhaps show us some more code. Where you set up elements like the tracks int, the playlist array, label you're referring to etc.?

Comment: and what is type of `tracks` is it NSUInteger or something else?

Comment: Wow, that was a fast down vote... I declared `tracks` as an `NSUInteger` in the header.  And `playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` in the `init` method.  I set the label up in the interface builder.

Comment: And the label is hooked up with an outlet I presume? Where's the code updating the label?

Comment: I set the binding up in the interface builder under the binding inspector, not programmatically.  Maybe this is the issue?  I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: Almost certainly. Your class has no knowledge of what you've done in the interface-builder until you hook up what needs to be hooked up.

Comment: Since the table view is populated with the items in the array, would it be easier to get a count of the rows in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you correctly registered `playlist` as a [dependent key](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE)

You need to specify that changes to the playlist object means that `trackCount` will change.

This is all part of [KVO compliance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA).

**Example**

Taken more or less exactly from the link to the documentation I've given you.

Add this to your implementation file:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key {

    NSSet *keyPaths = [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"trackCount"]) {
        NSArray *affectingKeys = @[@"playlist"];
        keyPaths = [keyPaths setByAddingObjectsFromArray:affectingKeys];
    }
    return keyPaths;
}
```

`keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` is part of the `NSKeyValueObservingProtocol`.

What this snippet does is it says that any changes to playlist will trigger a change in trackCount. So any observers of trackCount will be notified of a possible change to trackcount when playlist changes.

Comment: I have not done this and I'm not entirely sure how to implement it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have not initialised the array `playlist`.

```
playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Or you are not calling `trackCount` method.

```
NSUInteger someValue=[self trackCount];
```

Comment: Can you give me a little guidance on calling the method correctly?